# How to pass an expression as an argument/parameter?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, arguments, expression

Say I have a polynomial function f(x), and I want to use this expression into either the expression g(x) or h(x), depending on which the user chooses. Is this possible?

for example

```
int main() {

   float fexpression = /* polynomial function f(x) here */;    

   /* some code where user picks g(x) or h(x) */

   if (/* gexpression == true */)
        cout << gfunction(fexpression);
   else /* h expression == true */
        cout << hfunction(fexpression);

return 0;
    }

 float gfunction(float j){

     float var = /* some function representing g(f(x)) == g(j) */;
  return var;
  }

 float hfunction(float j){
       float var = /* some function representing h(f(x)) == h(j) */;
  return var;
      }
```

it just doesnt seem right to me that I can pass a variable that is an expression, such as

```
float fexpression = ....
```

Comment: It's not clear where you set / use `x`. Is `fexpression` a string? How do you evaluate f(x)?

Comment: well I want it to be a polynomial expression with variables. For example, (5*(pow(x,4))) + (3*(pow(x, 3))) + (10 * x) - 5

Comment: Presumably it is evaluated during the assignment, so you are actually passing the value not the expression. This does require you to define `x` somewhere...

Comment: Hint: the fact that `fexpression` is a `float` tells you that by the time you get to the function call, it is no longer an expression...

Comment: Hmm... yeah I just set it as a float just because. But I can't evaluate the expression first because there are dynamic variables plugged into the expression later.

Comment: You are not showing `x` anywhere... how is it known to `gfunction()`?

Comment: How do you expect the computer to evaluate an expression with unknown variables? Since you are assigning to a `float`, that's all it can do...

Comment: Oh, yes I know. The code above was just a theoretical example. I left out declaring x and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a [function pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer).

Make the expression a function.

```
float fexpression( float x )
{
   return (5*(pow(x,4))) + (3*(pow(x, 3))) + (10 * x) - 5
}
```

This code, as you wrote it, will then pass the functionality itself.

```
   if (/* gexpression == true */)
        cout << gfunction(fexpression);
   else /* h expression == true */
        cout << hfunction(fexpression);
```

Comment: Is it possible to assign the function fexpression to a variable that will be passed later without first initiating x? and have a value of x assigned after the variable with fexpression is passed?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to explain details of this in the comment section of Drew's answer, but it got lost in the formatting... so had to start another answer.

@DrewDorman's is right in saying you need to just define your expression as a function:

```
float fexpression( float x )
{
   return (5*(pow(x,4))) + (3*(pow(x, 3))) + (10 * x) - 5
}
```

What is missing (for you) is the following (which you would get from reading Drew's link...):

define your `gfunction` as follows (for instance)

```
float gfunction(float (*funcp)(float)) {
    // lots of stuff to determine the value of x
    return (*funcp)(x);
}
```

This is how gfunction can evaluate your polynomial. Do something similar for `hfunction`

When you call gfunction, you have to reference `fexpression` as follows:

```
cout << gfunction(&fexpression);
```

the `&` matters... it was also missing from Drew's answer.

Comment: @DrewDormann - cheers. This kind of back and forth is how SO is most valuable.

Comment: @Floris What does including (*funcp)(float) in the parameters do exactly? I read up on pointers but I'm still unclear on that. 
Does it cast the second float parameter as a pointer named funcp?

Comment: It is not a cast - it is a declaration. It tells the compiler: "when you interpret the parameters on the stack when I call this function, the first parameter is a pointer to a function". "I'm going to tell you where to find a function you will be using". In the same way that "int", "double" etc instruct the compiler how to interpret other parameters. Function pointers are the trickiest one of the bunch... But once you realize compilers just treat functions as "the next set of instructions - where are they", it gets easier to accept. Maybe.